# How check that the application has been updated?

Tags: ios, swift

There is a iOS application that is constantly running.
While the application is running, the iOS or MDM server can update application the new version application.
I need, with some delay, to detect application updates from a running application and complete the running version of the application.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "detect application updates from a running application." If you mean "detect when the application is about to be updated," that is not possible. The application will be killed, but you won't know why (and in many cases you won't even know that it happened). Also, it's unclear what you mean by "a iOS application that is constantly running." There is no supported way to have such an application. If you mean that you want to know, when you launch, that an update has occurred since the last time you were running, that is very straightforward.

Comment: "Also, it's unclear what you mean by "a iOS application that is constantly running." 

In single app mode application constantly running forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can to check app iOS version by:

```
var version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

and then at AppDelegate you implement force_version_update func with delay time.

Unfortunately, only the user directly to update the IOS app from the AppStore

Comment: Is it possible for an application to gain read access to the binary of the application itself?
Considering the checksum of binary it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in one of my Apps by using following steps:

1. Storing the current version in UserDefaults
2. Retrieving latest version from backend/server using Rest API
3. Compare the two and if not same ask user to update the App

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a different case. In my case, the application will accurately update itself without user intervention, since the user is not allowed to do anything at all.

Comment: Is the problem resolved for you? If not did you try implementing `applicationWillTerminate(_:)`?  [Refer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

Comment: No, the problem is not solved. The problem is not to complete the application, but to determine that the operating system has updated the application. As I understand it, the update takes place in the background while the application is running.
And only then, if the application is not active, then the operating system reloads the application. But if the application is constantly active, it will not be restarted.

At the moment, we are restarting the entire device remotely from the MDM server. But this is a bad decision.